# Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, locale

Been having a problem for some time now, and scouring the internet for solutions they always refer back to what the user was doing when the problem occurred. For me, the same problem occurred during two different actions, making me think it might have something to do with Python's permissions.

Trying to install fswebcam, the following code pops up:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
LookupError: unknown encoding: UF-8
```

Trying out solutions from other forums, I tried updating Python to 3.7.1, according to https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f. When installing the packages, the same error would pop up (also specifying UF-8).
Most forum posts refer to actions other than installing fswebcam while the problem occurs, and I can't seem to find what goes wrong.

When trying to update Xserver, in order to get startx working again, the same Fatal Python error occurs.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-legacy
```

From last post at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171843

The versions of my Linux kernel and firmware respectively are as follows:

> Linux Olijf 4.14.50-v7+ #1122 SMP Tue Jun 19 12:26:26 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
>
> Jun  7 2018 15:31:38
>   Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
>   version 4800f08a139d6ca1c5ecbee345ea6682e2160881 (clean) (release)

I feel like I have by now seen every forum post about the locale encoding being inaccessible, but I hope that I am wrong and someone knows what might be the problem. Hope I provided enough information, if not I'm happy to follow directions!

Edit: output from the terminal command locale

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_GB.utf8
```

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of the terminal command `locale`.

Comment: Hmm.. It complains about the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale even if the `locale -a` command shows that it has been generated. Weird. Maybe try to re-generate the locale: `sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: Unbelievable! I knew it had to be simple but... Brilliant! Just brilliant! Fswebcam installs now smoothly and runs well... Tack så mycket!!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please post the solution as an answer (it's fine to answer your own question). Then in a couple of days you'll be able to accept the answer as the solution and that way mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided by Gunnar Hjalmarsson,
the answer to my problem:

'Hmm.. It complains about the en_GB.UTF-8 locale even if the locale -a command shows that it has been generated. Weird. Maybe try to re-generate the locale: sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8'

This fixed it! Thank you so much!!